# When using mysqli_multi_query for two columns, the ordering is not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My code is:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `chat` 
          WHERE fromthe =  '$email' and tothe='theadmin' order by id desc;";
$query .= "SELECT * FROM  `chat` 
          WHERE fromthe =  'theadmin' and tothe='$email' order by id desc";
mysqli_multi_query($con, $query);
```

When using this query I get results, but my concept not working.

The concept is:
This is used in a chat application on php server, I am using this query to get messages between client and admin. I have to order the `id`'s of this results as descending.

The result I am seeing is:
It is ordering admins message with it's `id` and ordering clients message with it's `id`. I want order `id` as descending of both results together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be you need  a single query based on UNION ALL

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `chat` 
      WHERE fromthe =  '$email' and tothe='theadmin' 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT * FROM  `chat` 
      WHERE fromthe =  'theadmin' and tothe='$email' order by id desc";
```

*Anyway you should avoid the use of php var in sql (you are at risk for sqlinjection )  .. you should take a look  at prepared  statements and binding param*